# Recycler View updates when acticity resumed with Firebase Database android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-design-library

I am trying to make a Blog App in android for my portfolio and I am having a problem. When I open the app the recycler view does not show anything but when I press the back button and open the app it updates the recycler view and this problem I am facing when running the app on real device I have tried running them in two emulators one is Nexus 5 and another Pixel 2 and they work fine and load the recycler view in first attempt only.

This is the activity's code:--

```
package raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp.Adapters.HomePostAdapter;
import raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp.PostPackage.PostPOJO;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, HomePostAdapter.CustomItemClickListener {
    public ArrayList<PostPOJO> mListOfPost = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    HomePostAdapter homePostAdapter;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private NavigationView mNavView;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mNavView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerView);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, mToolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

        drawerToggle.syncState();

        mNavView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        homePostAdapter = new HomePostAdapter(mListOfPost, MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(homePostAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Toast.makeText(this, "START", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mListOfPost = new ArrayList<>();
        topics = new ArrayList<>();

        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference referenceTopic = database.getReference("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Topics");

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Log inned with user " + currentUser.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            referenceTopic.orderByKey().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        topics.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getValue(String.class)));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            DatabaseReference referencePost = database.getReference("Posts");

            referencePost.orderByKey().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), dsp.child("topic").getValue().toString());

                        Iterator<String> iterator = topics.iterator();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            String str = iterator.next();
                            if (dsp.child("topic").getValue().equals(str)) {
                                PostPOJO postPOJO = dsp.getValue(PostPOJO.class);
                                mListOfPost.add(postPOJO);
                            }
                        }

                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                        homePostAdapter.updateData(mListOfPost);
                        homePostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void signOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sign_out:
                signOut();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Profile:
                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
                startActivity(profileIntent);
                break;

            case R.id.Topics:
                Intent topicsIntent = new Intent(this, Topics.class);
                startActivity(topicsIntent);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void startPostActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Post.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Post.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("POJO", homePostAdapter.mListOfPost.get(position));
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is recycler view's code:--

```
package raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp.PostPackage.PostPOJO;
import raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp.R;

/**
 * Created by Lenovo on 03-12-2017.
 */

public class HomePostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomePostAdapter.viewHolder> {

    public ArrayList<PostPOJO> mListOfPost;
    private Context context;
    CustomItemClickListener listener;

    public interface CustomItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position);
    }


    public HomePostAdapter(ArrayList<PostPOJO> mListOfPost, Context context,CustomItemClickListener customItemClickListener) {
        this.mListOfPost = mListOfPost;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = customItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_item,parent,false);
        final viewHolder mViewHolder = new viewHolder(view);




        return mViewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(viewHolder holder, int position) {
        PostPOJO postPOJO = mListOfPost.get(position);
        holder.titleTextView.setText(postPOJO.getTitle());
        holder.subTitleTextView.setText(postPOJO.getSub_title());

        Boolean wasImageSet=false;

        Iterator<String> iterator = postPOJO.grouped_elements.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            String str = iterator.next();

            if(str.startsWith("URL::")){
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(str.substring(5))
                        .into(holder.headerImage);
                wasImageSet = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(wasImageSet==false){
            holder.headerImage.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emptyimage));
        }

       holder.bind(position);
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<PostPOJO> postPOJOS){
       this.mListOfPost = postPOJOS;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListOfPost.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView headerImage;
        private TextView titleTextView;
        private TextView subTitleTextView;

        public viewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            headerImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerImage);
            titleTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            subTitleTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sub_title);
        }

        public void bind(final int position){
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            });
        }


    }
}
```

Log on emulator is:---

```
12-03 16:39:26.864 12822-12822/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-03 16:39:26.928 12822-12822/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-03 16:39:27.113 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
12-03 16:39:27.115 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
12-03 16:39:27.119 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
12-03 16:39:27.122 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
12-03 16:39:27.170 12822-12843/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
12-03 16:39:27.179 12822-12843/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
12-03 16:39:27.179 12822-12843/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
12-03 16:39:27.207 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( sLZMm3S1o8TESyFjjy11mYEdVTG3 ).
12-03 16:39:27.245 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
12-03 16:39:27.258 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: -2093232798
12-03 16:39:27.260 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
12-03 16:39:27.261 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
12-03 16:39:27.298 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-03 16:39:27.329 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Collection enabled
12-03 16:39:27.330 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: App package, google app id: raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp, 1:967774314306:android:75a87ded59f6ecc8
12-03 16:39:27.346 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11717
12-03 16:39:27.346 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-03 16:39:27.347 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                        adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp
12-03 16:39:27.347 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
12-03 16:39:27.400 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-03 16:39:27.493 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-03 16:39:27.525 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
12-03 16:39:27.525 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
12-03 16:39:27.571 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
12-03 16:39:27.639 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-03 16:39:27.640 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 17890383
12-03 16:39:27.662 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
12-03 16:39:27.665 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3708820839437256875}]
12-03 16:39:27.669 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
12-03 16:39:27.674 12822-12849/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
12-03 16:39:27.687 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
12-03 16:39:27.689 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
12-03 16:39:27.757 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-03 16:39:27.757 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
12-03 16:39:27.757 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
12-03 16:39:27.757 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
12-03 16:39:27.758 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-03 16:39:27.780 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa6f84540: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
12-03 16:39:27.797 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6f84540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa6f833e0)
12-03 16:39:27.799 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
12-03 16:39:27.799 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
12-03 16:39:27.799 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
12-03 16:39:27.799 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
12-03 16:39:28.009 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6f84540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa6f833e0)
12-03 16:39:28.093 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6f84540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa6f833e0)
12-03 16:39:28.138 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6f84540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa6f833e0)
12-03 16:39:28.177 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FA: Connected to remote service
12-03 16:39:28.178 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
12-03 16:39:29.645 12822-12832/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=30KB
12-03 16:39:29.645 12822-12832/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=30KB
12-03 16:39:29.645 12822-12832/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
12-03 16:39:29.669 12822-12850/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa6f84540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa6f833e0)
12-03 16:39:30.871 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/MainActivity: Cooking
12-03 16:39:30.883 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/MainActivity: Programming
12-03 16:39:30.944 12822-12822/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
12-03 16:39:31.061 12822-12832/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=34KB, data=54KB
12-03 16:39:31.063 12822-12832/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=34KB, data=54KB
12-03 16:39:31.063 12822-12832/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
12-03 16:39:31.063 12822-12832/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
12-03 16:39:31.063 12822-12832/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
12-03 16:39:33.629 12822-12846/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Log on real mobile is:--

```
12-03 16:41:11.099 2211-2211/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-03 16:41:11.199 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
12-03 16:41:11.203 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
12-03 16:41:11.212 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
12-03 16:41:11.222 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( sLZMm3S1o8TESyFjjy11mYEdVTG3 ).
12-03 16:41:11.223 2211-2232/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
12-03 16:41:11.232 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
12-03 16:41:11.242 2211-2232/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
12-03 16:41:11.242 2211-2232/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
12-03 16:41:11.260 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
12-03 16:41:11.261 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
12-03 16:41:11.283 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Collection enabled
12-03 16:41:11.284 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: App package, google app id: raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp, 1:967774314306:android:75a87ded59f6ecc8
12-03 16:41:11.285 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11717
12-03 16:41:11.286 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-03 16:41:11.286 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp
12-03 16:41:11.286 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
12-03 16:41:11.299 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-03 16:41:11.302 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-03 16:41:11.309 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-03 16:41:11.309 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-03 16:41:11.462 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
12-03 16:41:11.462 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
12-03 16:41:11.476 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
12-03 16:41:11.476 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
12-03 16:41:11.526 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-03 16:41:11.526 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 11707769
12-03 16:41:11.535 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
12-03 16:41:11.543 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
12-03 16:41:11.543 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-7835563879800379359}]
12-03 16:41:11.546 2211-2241/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-03 16:41:11.565 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-03 16:41:11.574 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
12-03 16:41:11.574 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
12-03 16:41:11.577 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
12-03 16:41:11.633 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-03 16:41:11.638 2211-2241/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8909_LA.BR.1.2.5_RB2__release_AU (I9d3821c5ab)
                                                                            OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
                                                                            Build Date: 02/24/16 Wed
                                                                            Local Branch: mybranch18408715
                                                                            Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.5_rb2.32
                                                                            Local Patches: NONE
                                                                            Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
12-03 16:41:11.639 2211-2241/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-03 16:41:11.652 2211-2241/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-03 16:41:11.945 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/FA: Connected to remote service
12-03 16:41:11.945 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
12-03 16:41:13.556 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
12-03 16:41:13.633 2211-2241/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
12-03 16:41:13.640 2211-2241/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/RenderScript: 0xb7a6a9d8 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
12-03 16:41:14.419 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/MainActivity: Cooking
12-03 16:41:14.421 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp D/MainActivity: Programming
12-03 16:41:14.433 2211-2211/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@f2c1b9f time:11295907
12-03 16:41:17.363 2211-2235/raghuveer.singh.bhardwaj.blogapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: try removing `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` line.

Comment: i tried that not working

Answer (score 0):

Try removing onStart method and copy the entire code to onCreate method.

OnStart is called several time during a lifecycle but onCreate is created once. So, you would want to put those firebase code in onCreate.

Its working on back button pressed and reopening the app because that's when onStart is called again.

Comment: When i debug the app and the time on real mobile its working when the app is resumed its giving W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value. this message

Comment: You can check if the current user is null or not in the previous activity and pass intent to this activity. In short, remove the if portion to check the user in this activity. @Raghuveer

Comment: Hey Bro i recently solved the problem now i will post one more problem i am having because of piccasso i think which says out of memory

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem through two steps:-

1)I moved the code of updating the recyclerview in oncreate.

2)I perfromed the post query i have completed populating the topic array list by pasting the post query and recycler view updation code after the for loop of data snapshot in ondatachange of topic query.

Yeah its bit confusing to explain.